# How to test Symfony2 api with DunglasAngularCsrfBundle

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I use Symfony2 with DunglasAngularCsrfBundle and when i run my PHpunit test it get error {"code":403,"message":"Bad CSRF token."}

If auth user with http basic

```
self::$user_client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'user1@mail.com',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'user1',
    'HTTP_HOST' => static::getHost()
));
```

This condition return false in EventListener\AngularCsrfValidationListener

```
if (!$value || !$this->angularCsrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($value)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Bad CSRF token.');
    }
```

generated token in test not equal, i try another auth like this:

```
protected function logIn($email)
{
$this->client = static::createClient();

$user = $this->client->getContainer()
    ->get('doctrine')
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
    ->findOneByEmail($email);

$providerKey = static::$kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());


$session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');
$session->set('_security_'.$providerKey, serialize($token));
$session->save();
$cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());

$this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
```

}

token not created. Return false in Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager::isTokenValid:

```
 $this->storage->hasToken($token->getId())
```

Please help to resolve this issue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
self::$client->request('GET', '/')
```

set token in cookie